# imagemagick - text decoration - line height

Tags: image, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'd like to have a line under my text created by imagemagick's convert like this:

```
convert -size 5000x5000 xc:none -quality 100 -font Norwester  -pointsize 720 -fill white -draw " decorate underline text 200,2500 \"T-SHIRT\"" out.png
```

which works pretty well except that the height of the line is like 1 pixel which is almost invisible under a 720px font.

Is there any way to change my code to have a thicker line under my text?

My current IM version is 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.4 or 8:6.9.11.60+dfsg-1.3 .

Answer (score 1):

Works fine for me on IM 6.9.12-50 Q16. The underline is the thickness of the text font.  Either you have a buggy version or the font is the issue.

```
convert -size 5000x5000 xc:black -quality 100 -font Ubuntu  -pointsize 720 -fill white -draw " decorate underline text 200,2500 \"T-SHIRT\"" out.jpg
```

[image]